# Is it a common practice to do all the work for PhD supervisor?

Tags: publications, phd, supervision

My PhD supervisor claims being first author of all the work I do. I also write research proposals for his grants and the rest of our group, he just redirects their emails to me and pretends that he's writing it.

He refuses to start my PhD programme - no idea for a possible subject.

I'm depressed, because I do not get ANY training or advice from him, just "write something fast with a big impact". I haven't even got a specific subject to work on. We basically meet each other during conferences or holidays. He does not correct any mistakes and barely knows what I'm actually doing. I'm about to quit my PhD completely... or leave academia just afterwards.

For obvious reasons I can't compare this situation with other universities, so that I'd be grateful for your opinion.

Comment: Absolutely quit. Find yourself a supervisor that does not abuse you.

Comment: Sounds like you're having a rough time bjp. Unfortunately, your question isn't really suitable for this website because it is very specific to your circumstances and no one here could give you much good advice without knowing all the gritty details. But don't get more depressed. Instead try and find another PhD student you can talk to about what's going on. Also, there's no shame in doing a PhD with the intention to leave academia afterwards, nor is there any shame in realising that academia isn't for you during the PhD and quitting out in the middle.

Comment: How is the situation for the other students this person 'advises'/'mentors'? Esp. former ones.

Comment: I think he tries to elongate the period they are PhD students, as 'dependent' workers. Any contacts with external world (e.g. other professors) is strictly prohibited, everyone works alone + he as 1st author. Former PhD students became lecturers (degradation), one of them is associate professor now and they still work together. He does not provide any research goals that he want to accomplish. It is confusing for me as a youngest member of the 'group'.

Comment: Agree with @WetlabWalter — difficult without knowing the concrete context, *but* those former PhD students might give you some advice (even if it's only J.Doe's *run!*). Much depends on what you have already invested (can you get anything out of it/take with you) but you should avoid the sunk cost fallacy. You could discuss the timetable for your PhD with the 'supervisor' and if you get none or it's violated take that as the final straw. In general, think beyond current situation in career terms. And you cannot (normally) have one without good supervision.

Comment: Don't quit, just change the supervisor. What year in the PhD program are you?It is in Eu/US?If it is in the start, then changing the supervisor is not a problem.

Comment: **Don't walk. Run.** Fire your advisor immediately.  You can do better.

Comment: How much time are you into the PhD?

Comment: Another question to check: why did you choose this superviser? Fame? Topic? Other reasons? This will help you make up your mind.

Comment: I'm into the business for like 2 years now, without subject and without my PhD actually started (I'm from Poland - we've got additional habilitation, unlike in english-speaking world). I'm working as a "assistant". Why I have chosen this one? He's the only true scientist in the whole University... Unfortunately.

Comment: Watch on YouTube how osain bolt runs, and then run from your supervisor faster then him.

Comment: @bjp "He's the only true scientist in the whole University."

A true scientist does not behave in any of the ways that you described.

Answer (score 21):

*Assuming* all that you state of your supervisor is true, i.e.,

- Claiming primary authorship of all of your work
- Making you write grants and claiming it as his own
- Refusing to start your PhD programme

Then you met up with one of the classic cases of an *abusive supervisor*. If that is the case, then **continue no further as his student**. Spare no time in moving away as you won't make much progress (at all) with such an advisor.

I feel sorry for the situation that has caused you to despise the PhD degree itself. My honest advice would be to change your advisor, not your path. If the current advisor claims primary authorship over your writings and grant proposals, then it is only a proof that you are really a worthy candidate for a PhD! Quit your supervisor, not your PhD!

Think deep and make your decision wisely, as it is yours to make.

Answer (score 0):

Someone close to me was in a similar situation.  He chose to keep the formal advisor but work informally with another person in his department.  This might be an option for you to consider.  (In addition to the obvious option already described, of switching advisors.)

Start with getting to know the people in your department.  Try to talk to people about their work, about your interests.  (Save the complaining for a later stage in the relationship.)

If you don't strike gold in your department, read an article that you are interested in, contact the author, strike up a conversation -- it might lead to a collaboration!

In short, pretend that you are a post-doc.

---

Edit to take comment into account ("Why I have chosen this one? He's the only true scientist in the whole University... Unfortunately"):

If I were in your shoes, I would be careful to arrange for a new advisor and a transfer institution *before* quitting.  Thus, the advice in the comments ("walk, don't run") shouldn't be followed too literally.  If there were someone good you could switch to in your own university, it would be different.

This is kind of like when you are in a bad job.  It's usually best to find a different job *before* quitting the present job.

Note, if the university you are enrolled in is as bad as you say, then they may be rather lax in their requirements for graduation from the PhD program.  Read some published theses in your field to find out.

Your strange advisor may sort of boot you out with a PhD after a certain period of time.  That might leave you with a strange taste in your mouth.  If that happens, no worries, just grab that piece of paper and run with it, to a two-year postdoc with someone who can give you plenty of guidance (almost as though you were his or her PhD student).

Comment: Working in secret under his nose is a dangerous business, if (or rather, when) he finds out, you are up for a world of pain.

Comment: @Davidmh - It doesn't have to be hidden, and shouldn't be, in general.  If following my procedure would not work without subterfuge, then clearly the OP would have to sever the formal advisor-advisee relationship.

Comment: From the OP's comment: "Any contacts with external world (e.g. other professors) is strictly prohibited, everyone works alone", so, unfortunately, this is not an option.

Comment: @Davidmh - Thank you for bringing that to my attention.  Okay, this does fit the classic pattern of an abuser.